# Authenticating a Windows client to a Samba share

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, samba, authentication

I have a Samba network share being served by a Linux machine.  The share is read-only unless you give it a username and password.  I want my Windows 7 client machine to connect to it.

It appears that the Windows machine is connecting as a guest because it does not have write access.  The Windows machine never asks me whether or not it should connect as a guest or with a username.

How do I make the Windows machine authenticate?  Where do I input my password?  This seems like such a simple thing yet I am totally confused.  On Mac OS and Linux, it simply asks you for a username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click on My Computer and click Map Network Drive.  There you can specify the server you want to connect to and also a user to connect as.  You will need to make sure any existing connections to that server (seen & unseen) are cleared out beforehand.  The "unseen" factor includes hidden IPC$ shares.  If you click start, type cmd, then type "net use", you'll see if there are any hidden connections.

Comment: Thank you so much.  How convenient is it that there is no Map Network Drive icon/menu item in the Network Places panel.  You gotta hand it to those Windows guys for putting things in the least obvious spot.  They've perfected it to an art form =D